# What's an example of a weakly closed nil-subset whose enveloping algebra is not nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, algebras

Let $A$ be an associative $k$-Algebra. $W\subseteq A$ is said to be weakly closed if there is a $\gamma\colon W^2\to k$ such that $W$ is closed under the $γ$-bracket $[a,b]_γ=ab+γ(a,b)ba$.

Jacobson proves in his book about Lie algebras (Chap. II, Solvable and nilpotent lie  algebras):

**Theorem** Let $W$ be a weakly closed subset of the Endomorphism algebra of a finite-dimensional vector space. If $W$ is nil (i.e., for every element $w\in W$, $w^k=0$ for some $k$), the enveloping associative algebra of $W$ is nilpotent.

The assumption makes it appear that the statement ceases to be true if we have an algebra other that $\mathrm{End}_k(V)$.  What's an example of a nil $W$ weakly closed in $A$ such that the enveloping algebra is not nilpotent?